# Loop Trick - How to show one attribute if...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, for-loop

I'm looking for a function we can use in a loop to do this:

```
<% for rink in @rinks_in_region %>  
    <%= rink.city #Show Only if city (n-1) != n %> 
    <%= link_to_rink(rink.name+" Ice Rink",rink) %>
    <br>
<% end -%>
```

Basically just show the city only if it's different than the previous one.

Make sense? Thanks for your help!

Alextoul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `group_by` method on `@rinks_in_region` to group rinks by city and then use those groupings to display cities and rinks. It returns a hash mapping the thing you are grouping by, city in this case, to the values in the original collection that are in that group. So:

```
<% @rinks_in_region.group_by(&:city).each_pair do |city, rinks| %>  
  <%= city %> 
  <% rinks.each do |rink| %>
    <%= link_to_rink(rink.name+" Ice Rink",rink) %>
    <br/>
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: You can also use `.group_by(&:city)` since you are just returning a single method/property of @rings_in_region.

Comment: First time I hear of this group_by method. Awesome stuff. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
<% prev_city = nil -%>
<% for rink in @rinks_in_region %>
    <%= rink.city if rink.city != prev_city %>
    <% prev_city = rink.city -%>
    <%= link_to_rink(rink.name+" Ice Rink",rink) %>
    <br>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a ruby answer, but introduce a new variable, call it 'temp' or something and set that to the current element in your foreach. That way at the beginning of your loop you have access to last loops element.

```
temp = ''
    <% for rink in @rinks_in_region %>  
        <%= rink.city #Show Only if city != temp %> 
        <%= link_to_rink(rink.name+" Ice Rink",rink) %>
        <br>

temp = city

    <% end -%>

temp = ''
```

Comment: I see what you mean, thks a lot